# Is it possible to mix code statements with @_functionBuilder elements?

Tags: swift, uikit, function-builder

*Edited to have my current solution*

I'm writing a declarative animation framework, my current example looks like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    Animation(duration: 3, curve: .easeOut) {
      Code {
        self.label.alpha = 1
      }
      OnEnd {
        Animation {
          Code {
            self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.label.center.x + 100,
                                        y: self.label.center.y)
          }
        }
      }
    }.startAnimation()
  }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to drop `Code {}` so that code reads like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    Animation(duration: 3, curve: .easeOut) {
      self.label.alpha = 1
      OnEnd {
        Animation {
          self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.label.center.x + 100,
                                      y: self.label.center.y)
        }
      }
    }.startAnimation()
  }
}
```

My current Animation constructor looks like:

```
class Animation {
  init(duration: TimeInterval? = nil,
       curve: UIView.AnimationCurve? = nil,
       @AnimationBuilder build: @escaping AnimationBuilderClosure) {
  }
}
```

I also tried to add

```
class Animation {
  convenience init(duration: TimeInterval? = nil,
       curve: UIView.AnimationCurve? = nil,
       code: @escaping AnimationCodeBlock) {
    self.init(duration: duration, curve: curve, build: {
      return AnimationElements(elements: [Code(block: code)])
    })
  }

  // ...
}
```

But that leads to all the `Animation { }` code assuming it's the convenience initializer (understandably)

Comment: What about [`.onAppear(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onappear(perform:))?

Comment: It would be much better to set it once than setting the background color every view update.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to ask about particular code, the question about arbitrary code execution as a part of `@_functionBuilder ` builder

Comment: So code which is called every time the view body updates, within the view builder?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you did set up your function builder you can add an overload of `buildExpression` that takes `Void` as an argument and returns no result, e.g.:

```swift
static func buildExpression( _ statement: Void) -> [Expression] {
    return []
}
```

This allows statements like this in function builder blocks:

```swift
self.label.alpha = 1
```

Or empty statements (e.g. in `switch` cases that should not do anything):

```swift
()
```

**Edit: Fully working Solution**

This is a slightly simplified version of what was requested (with label initialization filled in to make it compile):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let label = UILabel(frame: .init(x: 30, y: 50, width: 200, height: 30))

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = "Hello World"
    label.alpha = 0
    view.addSubview( label)

    Animation {
      self.label.alpha = 1
      OnEnd {
        Animation {
          self.label.frame.origin = .init(x: 120, y: 300)
        }
      }
    }.startAnimation()
  }
}
```

The Animation type would look like this:

```
struct Animation {
  
  let block: () -> [OnEnd]

  init(@AnimationBuilder block: @escaping () -> [OnEnd]) {
    // save block for later execution
    self.block = block
  }

  func startAnimation() {
    var endBlocks: [OnEnd] = []
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
      // save OnEnd blocks for later execution and execute free statements
      endBlocks = self.block()
    } completion: { _ in
      endBlocks.forEach { $0.run() }
    }
  }
}
```

`OnEnd` looks like this then:

```
struct OnEnd {

  let block: () -> [Animation]

  init(@OnEndBuilder block: @escaping () -> [Animation]) {
    // save block for later execution
    self.block = block
  }

  func run() {
    block().forEach { $0.startAnimation() }
  }
}
```

Now we need two function builders to make the above code work. One for the Animation:

```
@_functionBuilder
enum AnimationBuilder {
  static func buildExpression(_ value: Void) -> [OnEnd] {
    []
  }
  static func buildExpression(_ value: OnEnd) -> [OnEnd] {
    [value]
  }
  static func buildBlock(_ values: [OnEnd]...) -> [OnEnd] {
    values.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

And one for completion:

```
@_functionBuilder
enum OnEndBuilder {
  static func buildExpression(_ value: Void) -> [Animation] {
    []
  }
  static func buildExpression(_ value: Animation) -> [Animation] {
    [value]
  }
  static func buildBlock(_ values: [Animation]...) -> [Animation] {
    values.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

The end result looks like this:

[image: Animation]

**Edit 2: Result of the transformation**

For reference, this is the result of the compiler transformations that are triggered by the function builder attributes:

```
Animation {
  let e0 = AnimationBuilder.buildExpression( self.label.alpha = 1)
  let e1 = AnimationBuilder.buildExpression( OnEnd {
    let e0 = OnEndBuilder.buildExpression( Animation {
      let e0 = AnimationBuilder.buildExpression( self.label.frame.origin = .init(x: 120, y: 300))
      return AnimationBuilder.buildBlock( e0)
    })
    return OnEndBuilder.buildBlock( e0)
  })
  return AnimationBuilder.buildBlock( e0, e1)
}.startAnimation()
```

**Edit 3: Control Flow**

It's probably a good idea to implement the rest of the builder methods to allow control flow statements (to the extent possible with function builders):

```
extension AnimationBuilder {
  // Allow if statements that don't have an else clause
  public static func buildOptional(_ elements: [OnEnd]?) -> [OnEnd] {
    elements ?? []
  }

  // Allow if/else and switch statements
  public static func buildEither(first elements: [OnEnd]) -> [OnEnd] {
    elements
  }

  // Allow if/else and switch statements
  public static func buildEither(second elements: [OnEnd]) -> [OnEnd] {
    elements
  }

  // Allow for..in loops (in Swift 5.4)
  public static func buildArray(_ elements: [[OnEnd]]) -> [OnEnd] {
    elements.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

Same for OnEnd blocks:

```
extension OnEndBuilder {
  public static func buildOptional(_ elements: [Animation]?) -> [Animation] {
    elements ?? []
  }
  public static func buildEither(first elements: [Animation]) -> [Animation] {
    elements
  }
  public static func buildEither(second elements: [Animation]) -> [Animation] {
    elements
  }
  public static func buildArray(_ elements: [[Animation]]) -> [Animation] {
    elements.flatMap { $0 }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when will `self.label.alpha = 1` be executed? I'm pretty sure the idea would be to add it to the component being built, which won't be happening this way (as the builder will simply ignore it). It may get executed at declaration time, which is not the desired result.

Comment: The builder closure would be stored as a property of the `Animation` class. The implementation would run the closure within the `animations` block and capture the `OnEnd` closures, which would then be executed in the `completion` block. (Assuming this function is used: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animate).

Comment: `self.label.alpha = 1` would then be executed in the `animations` block.

Comment: No, result builder attributes only work with closure literals. You can't store them, they are transformed in place, and get executed during transformation. Thus `self.label.alpha = 1` will be executed immediately when `Animation` is initialized, and only the results of the transformation will be stored as a property – which won't contain `self.label.alpha = 1`, only whatever `buildExpression(_:()) -> Expression` returns… and `buildExpression` won't be able to transform `self.label.alpha = 1` into anything meaningful because it will only ever see a `()`. Code would be executed out of order.

Comment: It's true that result builder attributes don't work with stored properties, but they don't have to. The _transformation_ happens during compile time (i.e. inserting build* methods). Execution is controlled by the implementor by calling the closure with `()`. The transformed function has the same type as the untransformed function, so it can be stored as a normal property (`@escaping` is required in the function signature though). I added a working example to my answer.

Comment: Cool, you're taking advantage of the lazy way transformations are performed (and the closure executed) only when *accessing* the passed escaping closure property! I'd say this can be an acceptable answer **in this quite narrow special case** where an `Animation` contains some non-builder statements that need to be executed first, and then zero or more `OnEnd` blocks which need to be stored for later execution. This may be just fine for a simple animation builder. Should you want to mix builder and non-builder statements, their execution order may be difficult (or impossible) to get right.

Comment: Edited *my* answer to address some of this

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a solution that is tailored to the requirements of the question. If you needed to store the code inside the builder structure you would certainly need to capture it in a closure (as you suggested). It's probably a footgun (when mixing with control flow), but you could use `@autoclosure` to do that.

Comment: `static func buildExpression(_ value: @autoclosure () -> ()) -> [Component]`

Comment: You mean `@escaping @autoclosure`, right? :) I'd like to see a DSL that builds a collection of closures from closure collection builders and autoclosures…

Comment: Yeah, right, forgot the `@escaping`. But not a good idea to do that I guess ;)

Comment: `let value = doSomething(); doSomethingElse( value);` The first statement would't be captured by `buildExpression` and executed directly when the builder closure is called.

Answer (score 1):

*Edited to reflect on possible workarounds.*

You initialize an `Animation` object, which probably contains an array (or other collection) of closures. At a certain point you will call its `startAnimation()` method, which will probably execute the closures sequentially. So any "code statement" such as `self.label.alpha = 1` you want to use in the build block would need to be added to the list of closures, rather than be executed immediately at declaration time.

However, when you pass a closure literal to a parameter with a [result builder](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0289-result-builders.md) (nee function builder) attribute (as you do in `init`), the following happens:

1. **The closure gets executed immediately when accessed.** This is the moment when `self.label.alpha = 1` will run, as will every statement in the closure.
2. The **return values** of these statements will be collected and recursively transformed by the various builder functions (`buildBlock`, `buildExpression`, etc.) into `Expression`s, `Component`s, and a `FinalResult` in the end (with `Component` being mandatory and the other two defaulting to the same type as `Component`). This is an iterative process where expressions are combined into components, and finally components into a final result.

   - Your builder functions must explicitly support all return types. For instance, if you want your build closure containing `self.label.alpha = 1` to compile, you need to make sure that a builder function (e.g. `buildExpression`) handles the return type `()`.
   - But even in that case, note that all the builder function will see from `self.label.alpha = 1` will be its return type of `()`! It won't know that `self.label.alpha = 1` was executed, only that *something* was executed and it returned `()`.

So you can put non-building code in a build closure (if you support all possible return types of each statement you want to use), but that code will be executed when the closure gets transformed.

**EDIT**: As seen in the other answer, you can control, via the `@escaping` attribute, the order in which these nested closures are executed. The statements inside them will be executed in sequence, and their return values (if explicitly supported by your builder functions) will be collected for later. This may actually be an acceptable solution in your case (with some weirdness, e.g. you can put the `OnEnd` block before, after, or in the middle of your animation statements, and it will still be executed at the end).

**In general, mixing building and non-building statements in a declarative DSL may be tricky since the latter will be executed outside the structure you're constructing by the build system, and the order of execution may be difficult to control.**

Just imagine a case where you want to build animation sequences:

```
Sequence {
    Animation {
        self.label.center.x = 100.0
    }
    self.label.center.x == 0.0
    Animation {
        self.label.center.x = 200.0
    }
}
```

When transforming the closure passed to `Sequence`, the statement `self.label.center.x == 0.0` will be executed immediately, whereas the two wrapped in `Animation` structs or objects will be transformed and added to the build result. Sure, you can also have your system specifically execute them immediately, and maybe even discard the build result, but I have to wonder if it's worthwhile to support two execution sequences for each closure parameter: one at the time of transforming the closure, and the other at the time of executing the sequence resulting from all the result builder transformations… all in order to save a little bit of typing.

I'd still go for a cleaner solution where you construct the entire animation hierarchy and execute it in one go. In that situation, what you would need in your builder closure is not `self.label.alpha = 1` but rather **an expression that returns `{ self.label.alpha = 1}` .**

I think the closest you can probably get to your idea is to support (via `buildExpression(_:)` and probably the introduction of a protocol that covers both building closures and void closures to be used as your type) something like this:

```
    Animation(duration: 3, curve: .easeOut) {
      { self.label.alpha = 1 }
      OnEnd {
        Animation {
          {
              self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.label.center.x + 100,
                                          y: self.label.center.y)
          }
        }
      }
    }.startAnimation()
```

You may also want to check out the new [multiple trailing closure syntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0286-forward-scan-trailing-closures.md) in Swift 5.3, maybe it can help in some special cases.

Also, the [`callAsFunction` method](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0253-callable.md) may have some benefits with closure parameters… Again, for some special cases that might apply to your needs.